# Amazon ECS free tier pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

A quick question,

I have two volumes allocated with 30GB and 8GB of space.

And now I just reviewed the report and am being charged for 2.756 GB-Mo of usage.

Then I read that `$0.00 per GB-month of provisioned storage under monthly free tier     30 GB-Mo`,

so if I were to remove the 8GB volume while keeping the 30GB up and running, I wouldn't be charged providing that the 30GB is free.  Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: what did amazon say ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product/service pricing, and should be addressed to the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, as long as you don't go over any of the EBS free tier limits:
30 GB of Amazon EBS Standard volume storage plus 2 million IOs and 1 GB snapshot storage
Per http://aws.amazon.com/free/